# Validating custom tumblr theme

Tags: validation, themes, tumblr

I am witing a custom tumblr theme. When I went to validate it using the W3C validator I got a bucket full of errors from the code tumblr inserts into the blog outside of my theme code. So I did troubleshooting 101 and installed their default theme and tried to validate it. I used the Redux theme. When I put it into the validator I get these 3 errors:

```
Line 2, Column 871: Stray doctype.

….0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Error Line 3, Column 67: Stray end tag html.

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

Error Line 3, Column 67: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

so my question, how critical is validation? The problem I'm trying to solve is that my custom theme is quite sluggish. I figured step 1 to speed it up would be use valid markup. But that does not seem possible. (Also getting buckets of errors from the FB G+ and TW button code that I have no control over). thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem with trying to validate a Tumblr theme is that there is specific code that Tumblr recognises, and needs, that an HTML validator will count as invalid. Although it is used in Tumblr, it is technically not correct as just html.

Code for blog posts such as

```
{block:Label}
```

may be flagged as invalid as the HTML validator doesn't know that it as correctly structured code for Tumblr. The validator may say that it is invalid when placed in a certain context such as in 'li' elements even though for Tumblr this is where it is meant to be placed.

Try using this validator as you can group errors by type, that way you can see if you have errors other than ones created by using Tumblr code.
http://validator.keegan.st/

Solve all the html errors and don't worry about the tumblr caused ones.